# IE8 label update via javascript issue

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, label

I am trying to use javascript to update the text in a html label.

It works in all browsers except IE8. In IE8 the label appears to be updated but is not displayed on the screen.

I've created demo code below that shows the issue.

Thanks

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script>
  function sendRequest() {               
    document.getElementById('errormessage').textContent="test";
    alert("textContent : "+document.getElementById('errormessage').textContent);
  }   
</script>

</head>

<body>

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="sendRequest();"> Click me</a>
   <br/>
  <label id="errormessage" style="color:#F00">&nbsp;</label>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('errormessage').innerHTML="test";
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to vary from browser to browser.

Comment: You could use jQuery, it should take care of browser inconsistencies.

Comment: Use jQuery to resolve browser inconsistencies in innerHTML? How?

Answer (score 2):

IE 8 and under doesn't have textContent.

Try this:

```
function setText(el, text){
    if(typeof el.innerText !== 'undefined')
        el.innerText = text;
    else
        el.textContent = text;
}

function getText(el){
    return el.innerText || el.textContent;
}

function sendRequest() {
    var el = document.getElementById('errormessage');
    setText(el, "test");
    alert("textContent : "+getText(el));
}
```

Comment: The *innerText* and *textContent* properties are strings, therefore the *typeof* test should test for that, e.g. `if (typeof el.textContent == 'string')`.