# JS: Add comma to a string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add comma to a string and show that into label through following function :

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="addCommas(this.value);" /> <br /><br />
<label id="result">Result: </label>
```

**JS**

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    var result = x1 + x2;
    document.getElementById('result').value = result;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4mLD/)

But won't show the result into label.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `No wrap - in <head>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Label doesn't use `value` to assign values. It uses `innerHTML`. Try the below.

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
```

As pointed out in comments, it is better to use `textContent` or  `innerText` options to set value (only for plain text) as they are safer than `innerHTML`.You can use it as shown below.

```
document.getElementById('result').textContent = result;
```

or

```
document.getElementById('result').innerText = result;
```

---

`innerText` property is **not supported** by **FireFox** and it uses the `textContent` property. Hence, the below method will work across browsers.

```
var resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');

if (typeof resultDiv.innerText === 'string') {
    resultDiv.innerText = result;
}
else {
    resultDiv.textContent = result;
}
```

**Sources:**

1. [IE8 label update via javascript issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370184/ie8-label-update-via-javascript-issue)
2. ['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

Comment: Worth nothing that `element.value` sets (or gets) the value property of the tag (e.g. `<input value="" />`), while `element.innerHTML` sets (or gets) the html that is between the starting tag and the end tag. If you are not wanting to set html, use `element.innerText` instead. An attacker could otherwise use your site to execute an arbitary script. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML).

Comment: innerText is not Supported by firefox. innerHTML is better for cross browser compatibility. Otherwise based on the type of browser, use textContent or innerText. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

Comment: @Akhil: Very valid point. Paulpro's answer in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370184/ie8-label-update-via-javascript-issue) has the correct method for using `innerText`/`textContent`. I will be updating my answer soon.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
```

instead of `.value`, use `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 3):

Use `innerHTML` instead of `value`:

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
```

**JSFIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/J4mLD/1/

**Also note,** to use inline event handlers in JSFIDDLE you must set the second dropdown to one of the nowrap options.